# How do I hide the IP & port in my URL with Apache?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, url, server

Some information:

- If I go to `mysite.com:9999` I get my site like `45.40.45.40:9999` .. and the `45.40.45.40` is the public ip of my router followed by the non-standard port used to connect my apache server on virtualbox on ubuntu.
- I use dns redirect from namecheap.com in order to redirect mysite.com to my public_ip:used_port_to_connect_Apache so it wil be like so: `45.40.45.40:9999` in the url after I get connected.

My question is: how can I convert/returned the '45.40.45.40:9999' to the original domain name which is mysite.com only?

What do I need to do? Is this an Apache configuration setting somewhere? It is a Virtual Host on Apache server.

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.com.conf:`

```
Listen 9999

<VirtualHost *:9999>

    <Directory /var/www/mysite.com/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ServerAdmin info@mysite.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite.com/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Comment: _“How can I convert/returned the '45.40.45.40:9999' to the original domain name which is mysite.com only?”_ - in the browser address bar, you mean? Well not at all, of course, _because_ your cheap DNS is set up to only _redirect_ to an IP address … You’ll need a proper DNS setup first.

Comment: Yes I mean in the browser address var exactly. Please help me set this up with proper dns with example so I can solve this issue